# Blocks can only contain strings error when saving to disk

Tags: php, phpexcel, cakephp-2.2

**Background**

I'm generating an Excel sheet that get's emailed to a certain address. It works perfectly on localhost (saves perfectly, can't test the mailing as I have no local mailserver running). When I host it, I run into some problems.

**What problems**

I've narrowed it down to this line:

```
$this->PhpExcel->saveToDisk($path);
```

`$path` is a custom path that is set at runtime. When I run that, it saves the file to disk but it gives me this:

[image]

This is a function in a custom helper class. Below is the code for the function:

```
public function saveToDisk($path) {
    // set layout
    $this->_View->layout = '';
    // headers
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // writer
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->xls, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save($path);
    // clear memory
    $this->xls->disconnectWorksheets();
}
```

But here is the catch. When I output it to browser, by changing `$objWriter->save($path);` to `$objWriter->save('php://output');` it gives me no error and exports the file perfectly.

**Question**

I've googled the error and tried my best to find the solution, but to no avail. The amount of info available on this error is staggeringly scarce or outdated. Could someone please tell me what it is that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing this line:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you've saved the file to disk, CakePHP still expects you to give it something to return to the browser that made the request, even if it's just a message to say that the file has been saved successfully, or that the email has been sent successfully.
If you're saving to disk, you don't want to send the headers because the server isn't going to be returning an Excel file, so no headers.

Comment: Tried echoing a simple line, the only thing it does is return the line above the template and then giving the error still.

Comment: ASsuming that CakePHP follows a MVC pattern then you shouldn't be echoing in a helper function, but returning something to the controller

Comment: If I return true from the helper function saveToDisk, it still gives me that error.